# Looking for a way to destructure object and pass optional arguments to another method if they are exist

Tags: javascript, typescript, javascript-objects, destructuring, optional-parameters

I want to make some properties optional and check whether propery exists and if it is I want to give it to this.UserService.update() method. I mean that i'm trying to update only those values which are passed to req.body.

> user.controller.ts

```
private updateUser = async (
        req: Request,
        res: Response,
        next: NextFunction
    ): Promise<Response | void> => {
        try {
            const id = req.user.id;

            //I want to check every value below exist whether it exists
            const { old_password, name, email, password } = req.body;

            // Some of they may be empty and if some of them are not I want to give  
            // them to the method below
            const updatedUser = await this.UserService.update(id, /* here */);

            return res.status(200).json({ updatedUser });
        } catch (error: any) {
            next(new HttpException(400, error.message));
        }
    };
```

> user.service.ts

```
public async update(
    id: string,
    old_password: string,
    name?: string,
    password?: string,
    email?: string
){}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] suitable for demonstrating your issue and only your issue when pasted as-is into a standalone IDE.  There should be no undeclared/undefined types/values.  You should also be very clear what your expected outcome is and how the code example you provide fails to achieve this.

Comment: Have you tried to use an object as a parameter and only set those values that you need? If yes, what problem did you get with that attempt?

Comment: I just have tried. Think you are right that is the better way to do it.

Answer (score 1):

You can directly check in update function:

```
public async update(
    id: string,
    old_password: string,
    name?: string,
    password?: string,
    email?: string
){
   if(name) {
       // Update name
   }
   if(email) {
       // Update email
   }
   // ....
}
```